# How to determine size of a specific slice of a static library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static library in my iOS project which contains slices for 4 architectures.  I am able to determine the architecture slice components of the static library with the command:

```
$ file myStaticLib.a
myStaticLib.a: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
myStaticLib.a (for architecture armv7):  current ar archive random library
myStaticLib.a (for architecture i386):   current ar archive random library
myStaticLib.a (for architecture x86_64): current ar archive random library
myStaticLib.a (for architecture arm64):  current ar archive random library
```

I wish to determine the *size* of a specific slice (arm64, e.g).  How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `lipo` command with the `-detailed_info` flag you are able to determine the size of a specific slice (amongst other details).  Usage as follows:

```
$ lipo -detailed_info myStaticLibrary.a

Fat header in: myStaticLib.a
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 4
architecture armv7
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7
    offset .......
    size .......
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture i386
    cputype CPU_TYPE_I386
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_I386_ALL
    offset .......
    size .......
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture x86_64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_X86_64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_X86_64_ALL
    offset .......
    size .......
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture arm64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_ARM64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_ALL
    offset .......
    size .......
    align 2^2 (4)
```

Comment: as a side note, I used a `man` page to determine this.  A colleague subsequently informed me that "you know you're a man when you use a man page".  I tend to concur.